# Json object is null when trying to parse

Tags: android, json

I have the following JSON String (below)that is returned from my server.
I can successfully extract the `resultCode` value which is "OK".

The problem I am having is extracting the `user` object, it is returning `null`.
I have looked at the following post on SO and i believed i was doing it correctly.

[json example that i have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986123/parsing-nested-json-object-in-android)

can anyone point me in the correct direction please?

```
{
    "resultCode":"OK",
    "configs":[
        {
            "configID":"1",
            "configName":"Data Limit",
            "configValue":"5000000"
        },
        {
            "configID":"2",
            "configName":"Connectivity Settings Frequency",
            "configValue":"55"
        },
        {
            "configID":"3",
            "configName":"User Tracking Frequency",
            "configValue":"56"
        },
        {
            "configID":"4",
            "configName":"Data Monitoring Frequency",
            "configValue":"57"
        },
        {
            "configID":"5",
            "configName":"User Device Frequency",
            "configValue":"58"
        },
        {
            "configID":"6",
            "configName":"Telephony Settings Frequency",
            "configValue":"59"
        },
        {
            "configID":"7",
            "configName":"Restrictions Settings Frequency",
            "configValue":"60"
        },
        {
            "configID":"8",
            "configName":"DateTime Settings Frequency",
            "configValue":"61"
        },
        {
            "configID":"9",
            "configName":"Advanced Settings Frequency",
            "configValue":"62"
        }
    ],
    "companyInfo":{
        "companyID":"1",
        "companyName":"Test Company",
        "webServiceGuid":"11E0662D-6672-406C-977A-4BE9124B3E35",
        "url":"http:\/\/xxx.yourofficeanywhere.co.uk\/",
        "portNumber":"51000"
    },
    "user":{
        "userID":"8",
        "samsungApiKey":"ABC",
        "surname":"Womersley"
    }

}
```

.

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(result);
Log.e(TAG, "mainObject = " + mainObject);

resultCode = mainObject.get("resultCode").toString();
Log.e(TAG, "resultCode = " + resultCode);
cv.put("resultcode", resultCode);

JSONObject user = mainObject.getJSONObject("user");
Log.e(TAG, "user object = " + user);
String userID = user.getString("userID");
Log.e(TAG, "userID = " + userID);
cv.put("userid", userID);
```

.

[EDIT1]
@flotto

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(result);
Log.e(TAG, "mainObject = " + mainObject);
JSONArray arr = mainObject.names();

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String name = arr.getString(i).toString();
    Log.e(TAG, "name = " + name);
}
```

result:

```
03-24 12:19:34.702 2893-4899/d.co.uk.d E/WebService: name = resultCode
03-24 12:19:34.702 2893-4899/d.co.uk.d E/WebService: name = configs
03-24 12:19:34.702 2893-4899/d.co.uk.d E/WebService: name = companyInfo
03-24 12:19:34.702 2893-4899/d.co.uk.d E/WebService: name = user
```

Comment: are your sure the user object is present in the server answer ? print out the complete json object at the begin of your function

Comment: @flotto Hi, i'm not sure what you mean. The full Json is posted above and the user object is within the result sent back from the server.

Comment: you can also check if  userobj.has("userID") then get userid

Comment: @turtleboy Your code seems to be corrent, that is why i am asking for additional debug output.

Comment: @flotto hi i have put some log outputs in EDIT1. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the log you are getting on crash !

Comment: @ashishdhiman2007  My appologies to all, i did not instantiate my Contentsvalue, so it was crashing when trying to add the resulCode to it. I simple mistake i overlooked. Thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 2):

Debug your code while  you're reading resultCode. In that moment "mainObject" should contain the user JSON object. if it's null, your server isn't sending you the correct JSON you're waiting.

Answer (score -1):

My appologies to all, i did not instantiate my Contentsvalue, so it was crashing when trying to add the resulCode to it. A simple mistake i overlooked. Thanks for everyones help

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, what a nice person you are !!...... Obviously you do not make any mistakes at all in programming and potentially life haha