# When using body-parser in node.js, how to get the key value in case insensitive mode?

Tags: node.js, case-insensitive, body-parser

When using body-parser in node.js, I want the send keys be case insensitive. suppose that we send a json such as { "Name" : "Dariush" } and I want to get 'Name' value, in two ways:

request.body.name
&
request.body.Name

But by default, just request.body.Name works! and I want the 'request.body.name' works too.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-process `request.body` keys with a lower case function and use only `request.body.name`.

Please, follow the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17945574/84661

There is also an express.js middleware for a related purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-uncapitalize