# handle complex anonymous JSON object

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I have complex anonymous JSON string.

For example:

```
{ someData: { test1: { test2: { test4: "data" }, test3: "my text" } } }
```

And I need to find one property in this JSON.
So, for example, if JSON contains `someData.test1.test3` property, then I need to use value of this property `my text`.
Is there a simple way to do (handle any level of nesting) that?

Comment: This should work: myObject["someData"][test1]["test3"], suppose myObject is of type JObject

Comment: *simple way to do (handle any level of nesting)*, what about a recursive solution?

Comment: yes, I think it's good idea, but unfortunately, I'm not good in recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use newtonsoft.json to parse this json to a JToken using

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse("{ \"someData\": { \"test1\": { \"test2\": { \"test4\": \"data\" }, \"test3\": \"my text\" } } }");
```

Then using SelectToken you can evaluate to a path and get the value you wish.

```
JToken result = token.SelectToken("$.someData.test1.test3");
```

Hope this helps!

See on DotNetFiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7cyRzv

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot, but what if I need case-insensitive check?

Comment: There is not a build in functionality for JsonPath to do case insensitive pathing. You'll have to code something on your own to run over the path and do case insensetive navigation. This question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704390/possible-to-search-case-insensitive-with-jsonpath @A.Gladkiy