# Gson dont bind List in Java

Tags: java, gson

I am trying to convert the following Json into a Java class. For some reason, Gson is not binding the list of Ecs.
The list of ecs is returning null. I have to do something for Gson to recognize the list. Please, What am I doing wrong?

These are my classes:

```
public class ConsultaProdutos {

    public String code;
    public String mensagem;
    public List<Retorno> retorno;

    // getters and setters
}

public class Retorno {
    public String idProduto;
    public String descricaoProduto;
    public String cardType;
    public List<ECs> ecs;

   //getters and setters
}

public class ECs {
    public String codigoEC;
    public String codigoTabelaCMM;
    public boolean habilitado;
    public boolean restricaoHabilitacao;

   //getters and setters
}

public class Teste {

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonSyntaxException, JsonIOException, FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ConsultaProdutos consulta = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("D:\\ConsultaProdutos.json"), ConsultaProdutos.class);

    for (Retorno retorno : consulta.getRetorno()) {
        if (retorno.getIdProduto().equals("18")) {
            List<ECs> ecs = retorno.getEcs();
            for (ECs ec : ecs) {
                if (ec.isHabilitado()) {
                    System.out.println("Tem Loja Virtual");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Não tem Loja Virtual");
                }
                    
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the Json:

```
{
"code": 200,
"mensagem": "Consulta realizada com sucesso.",
"retorno": [
    {
        "idProduto": 18,
        "descricaoProduto": "Loja Digital",
        "cardType": "LJVT",
        "ECs": [
            {
                "codigoEC": 179,
                "codigoTabelaCMM": "A419",
                "habilitado": false,
                "restricaoHabilitacao": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a case issue. The key is `ECs` and not `ecs`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333307) answer for details.  Valeu!

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/a/28957612/611819 a better answer to refer to, since it shows how to use the `@SerializedName` annotation? In the OP's case, one way to solve the problem is to annotate the `ecs` field with `@SerializedName("ECs")`

Comment: sorry, but in wich line and what class? because I use ecs just as a variable to access the value in man method

Comment: Class `Retorno` last attribute

Comment: But as mentioned by dnault you can use the annotation.