# Java Geocoding get lat/long from address string

Tags: java, json, google-maps, geocoding

Hello I am building an app in Java and I would like to get the latitude/longitude from a string address.

Every tutorials I found was quite old and doesn't seem to be the more "up-to-date" solution nowadays...

I guess I should use the Jackson API to convert JSON result to Java object after requesting Google Geocoding API which returns me results like these [JSON response](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Sayaji%20Hotel%20Near%20balewadi%20stadium%20pune&sensor=true)

According to this tutorial [Jackson convert JSON to Java object](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/) here is what I should use:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Staff obj = mapper.readValue(new URL("http://mkyong.com/api/staff.json"), Staff.class);
```

What I don't understand is if the "Staff class" ( which in my case will probably be a "Address class" ) should contains every attribute such as excepted in the JSON response or can I just choose those I am interested in ( lat/long) ?

Am I on the right way ?

**EDIT : It is not an android project**

Comment: [this one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int)) worked for me. you can also check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711499/get-latitude-and-longitude-with-geocoder-and-android-google-maps-api-v2)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson

Comment: Is the example you show specific to android ?

Comment: right, i thought you asked about android, sorry :)

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address

Comment: Once again the link you mentionned is about android :/

Comment: possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265833/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-a-json-object-from-google-geocode-using-java

Comment: Thank you very much this is the thread I was looking for ! I do have my answer now !