# Gson on Appengine

Tags: java, json, google-app-engine, gson

I am trying to use Gson to parse a class for storing as a blob on Google Appengine. I have added the file gson-1.7.1.jar to my build path and the web-inf/lib folder. My app compiles fine, but when attempting to run, the program fails with an error on `Gson g = new Gson();`

The error message is:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/google/appengine/repackaged/org/joda/time/DateTime;`

Has anyone found the same issue, or managed to get it to work? Any alternative JSON parsers that are known to work with appengine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSon itself has no dependency on joda. Are you importing from `repackaged`? That's not supported.

I'm using GSon 1.7.1 with SDK 1.5.4, and it works fine, but I don't have DateTimes represented in JSON.

Comment: That solved it. Organize import had chosen that package, rather than the com.google.gdata.data. DateTime option. I shouldn't just press finish! Worked ok as raw data into the datastore though weirdly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a known issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2388
Try to include [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library under WEB-INF/lib but I don't think that solves your problem.

I found [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) better than Gson (performance, project activity, better docs, ...). Take a look at this [related question that compares Jackson vs Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson).

Comment: I was unaware of the performance issue, and now Im going to look into swapping over. Thank you very the warning