# Java JSON library for generics

Tags: java, json, generics

Is there a JSON library for Java that can handle something like the following scenario:

```
public class BaseShapeSender<T extends Shape> {
{
  Collection<T> shapes;

  public void send
  {
    // Sending the shapes collection with JSON
  }
}

public class CircleSender extends BaseShapeSender<Circle>
{

}
```

Currently I'm using Jersey, but calling circleSender.send() with the above above scenario gives an exception

```
A message body writer for Java type, class java.util.ArrayList, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
```

even when using GenericEntity to send the collection (apparently Jersey can handle `Collection<Circle>` but the second level of generics is too much). So, I found myself duplicating the sending code in every subclass:

```
public class CircleSender extends BaseShapeSender<Circle>
{
  Collection<Circle> circles;

  public void send
  {
    // Sending the circles collection with JSON
  }
}
```

I would love to avoid that if possible since the sending logic is basically the same in all subclasses.

Comment: look at Google's GSon library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2431212/774444) Jackson supports both generics as well as polymorphism. GSON (which I've stuck with so far) does not until [issue 231](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=231) is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best JSON library for Java is Jackson [(http://jackson.codehaus.org](http://jackson.codehaus.org)).

We use it with Jersey and Resteasy and it's very good. You may automate object transformation without writing any factory or extra code. It's just automatic. There are a lot of advanced features and it is proven. I believe it is the standard for Java.

It also supports templating. Here is an example:

```
List<User> list = getUserService().getAllUsers();
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
getObjectMapper().writeValue(writer, list);
```

Comment: How does it integrate with Jersey? Don't they perform the same job (serializing Java objects to JSON strings and vice versa)?

Comment: No in fact Jersey manages the REST part. You need to convert the argurments (both input and output if you want to convert from/to JSON). When you convert the output to a string with Jackson, return it in the REST controller and is is sent in response. I found an example here http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/. I mainly use Resteasy which is a bit different.