# Writing data from objects in Java into an XML-file

Tags: java, xml, serialization

I have a piece of code as follows :

```
Person person1 = new Person();
person1.setName("abc");
person1.setAge(23);

Person person2 = new Person();
person2.setName("xyz");
person2.setAge(32);
```

And it needs to be represented in an XML-file as:

```xml
<Person>
    <person1>
        <name>abc</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </person1>
    <person2>
        <name>abc</name>
        <age>23</age>
    </person2>
</Person>
```

How do I do it?

Comment: have a look at Gson, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html

Comment: @Gopal Did you have a look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001458/json-java-object-to-json

Comment: I would recommend having multiple `person` elements instead of elements called `person1`, `person2`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for java-xml binding. You can JAXB binding and marshall.
Please check the link  http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ for sample.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use Serialization and XML-Parser (DOM for example). If you create an XML document then you can use XPath for querying.

I'd also consider on using http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

checking out at the code in your link i implemented it for my code. The code is as follows. I can write xml data only for one object and if I loop it just writes the last object. So when I tried to used the file in append mode it stopped functioning :

```
try {
    FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("file.xml", true);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NeuronNode.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

    // output pretty printed
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);


    for(int i=0; i<neuronNodes.length; i++)
    {
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(neuronNodes[i], file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(neuronNodes[i], System.out);
    }

} catch (JAXBException e | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have sorted out this problem using **Jackson Library and XMLMapper method**. Here is the code for the same.

```
  **MainClass.java:-**

  import java.io.IOException;

  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

   public class MainClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String xmlString = "   <Person>\r\n" + "       <person1>\r\n" + "           
        <name>abc</name>\r\n"
            + "           <age>23</age>\r\n" + "       </person1>\r\n" + "       
        <person2>\r\n"
            + "           <name>abc</name>\r\n" + "           <age>23</age>\r\n" + "       
       </person2>\r\n"
            + "   </Person>";

    ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    xmlMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    Person1 person1 = new Person1();
    person1.setName("abc");
    person1.setAge("23");

    Person2 person2 = new Person2();
    person2.setName("xyz");
    person2.setAge("32");

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setPerson1(person1);
    person.setPerson2(person2);

    String XMLStr = xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(person);

    System.out.println(XMLStr);

} }

    **Person.java:-**

   public class Person {
    Person1 Person1Object;
    Person2 Person2Object;

// Getter Methods

public Person1 getPerson1() {
    return Person1Object;
}

public Person2 getPerson2() {
    return Person2Object;
}

// Setter Methods

public void setPerson1(Person1 person1Object) {
    this.Person1Object = person1Object;
}

public void setPerson2(Person2 person2Object) {
    this.Person2Object = person2Object;
   } }

 **Person1.java:-**
public class Person1 {
private String name;
private String age;

// Getter Methods

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

// Setter Methods

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
} }

  **Person2.java:-**

  public class Person2 {
private String name;
private String age;

// Getter Methods

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

// Setter Methods

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
} }

  **OUTPUT:-**

       <Person>
         <person1>
              <name>abc</name>
              <age>23</age>
        </person1>
         <person2>
              <name>xyz</name>
              <age>32</age>
        </person2>
      </Person>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) for this many times.