# Is Default JSON LIB robust enough for real time twitter feed?

Tags: android

I am going to be consuming real time twitter feed and parsing it into objects for list view display.  I need robust solution is default json lib good enough for this task or do I need to use Gson / jackson lib?

Answer (score 0):

Check Gson and JackSon:

[GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

[JACKSON](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

**EDIT**: I did not see you mention this libraries. Yes, you should use them. This are robust
libraries, I used them to consume Json webservices and no problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

GSON/Jackson are just the libraries that allow you to parse json responses into objects or the other way round. However, the default implementation of json provided in android framework is capable enough of dealing any response string. The only drawback or turn-off is that you need to write extra code for simple things to get done.

Answer (score 0):

Following are some links with bench marking of JSON libs...

http://blog.novoj.net/2012/02/05/json-java-parsers-generators-microbenchmark/

http://danielywoo.blogspot.in/2011/04/json-java-libraries-benchmark-jsonlib.html

[Jackson Vs. Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)

And from the benchmark it looks like Jackson is the best and the fastest library for the JSON parsing...