# How one can represent the JSON Object in clean POJO?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java. I'm just parsing a string and getting the Json Response like this:

```
{
  "customer_id": "user",
  "merchantId": "xxxx",
  "cards": 
  [
    {
      "card_token": "715fc10a-e7b3-48a1-b6e7-09e71ac050f8",
      "card_number": "11111111",
      "card_isin": "23232",
      "card_exp_year": "2013",
      "card_exp_month": "12"
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason I wish I could be able to represent this in a POJO. Note that the `cards` field can consist of more than 1 field.

I'm new to Java. I don't want the code for doing it, but I want to know what is the best way to represent these structure in POJO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) that can easily convert json to java object (generic) and vice versa which further you can use for your POJO.

Comment: There is also another project http://jackson.codehaus.org/. I have never worked with GSON but I can tell that Jackson is very good implementation.

Comment: @Unsigned thank you for mentioning it, I will also have a look at it

Answer (score 2):

**-** `Manual` parsing of `JSON` to object will be a pain.

**-** Its better to go with `Jackson`, which i use.

**-** Or you can also choose `GSON` (created by google for its internal use initially).

**See this link for implementation example:**

http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Answer (score 1):

The two dominate JSON processors for Java are GSON (as @Abu points out in his answer) and Jackson. These libraries will help you map a Java POJO to a JSON object, and vice-versa.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson) is a comparison on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Jackson JSON. It's a bit faster and it works great with the [Java API for RESTful Services (JAX-RS)](http://jax-rs-spec.java.net/), the Java standarization for REST api's.

Here's a better comparison between the two: [Jackson Vs. Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)

To read an object from String, [checkout the ObjectMapper class](https://www.google.com/search?q=jackson+objectmapper).