# java api to convert java objects to json/json to java objects

Tags: java, json, api

I need a API to convert Java objects to Json and Json to Java objects.
i have searched over the net where i found **Gson** and **Jackson**.

can anyone help me what the difference between them, which is the best one to use.
or any other API suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.ca/2011/06/gson-v-jackson.html

Comment: use search and google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson

Comment: The search term "gson vs jackson" returned 11.400 results on google.com

Comment: [answer]  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson

the above link can provide a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You also have [Genson](http://code.google.com/p/genson/).

Its main advantages are ease of use, easily extensible and customizable, performance and nice features.

Some of its features are :

- handling polymorphic types
- ability to do things with and without annotations
- deserialize to pojos even if they don't provide a default constructor (and really pass the values not just null) without any additional code
- out of the box integration with Jersey (0 code)