# JSON Parsing- fetch value

Tags: java, android, json

I am having trouble parsing this JSON. I have the following data in a JSONObject o. How do i fetch the value for critics_score ?

```
{
"total":1,"
 movies":
 [{
      "id":"770672122",
      "title":"Toy Story 3",
      "year":2010,
      "mpaa_rating":"G",
      "runtime":103,
      "critics_consensus":"Deftly blending comedy, adventure, and honest emotion, Toy   Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works.",

      "release_dates":{"theater":"2010-06-18","dvd":"2010-11-02"},
      "ratings":
       {
                "critics_rating":"Certified Fresh",
                "critics_score":99,
                "audience_rating":"Upright", .......
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
    int criticsScore;
    try {
        criticsScore = myJsonObject.getJSONArray("movies").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("ratings").getInt("critics_score");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit: This is assuming your `JSONObject` is named `myJsonObject`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this blog post I wrote on parsing JSON files in Android platform, you might find it handy:

[JSON Parsing](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=746)

As a direction you would need to parse the `movies` object as a `JSONArray`, then get it's first item and extract the ratings `JSONObject` and then extract the `critics_score` `int` out of it.

Answer (score 1):

data_array['movies'][0]['ratings']['critics_score']

Use this to help read your JSON - http://jsoneditoronline.org/

To create the object data_array I used this, var data_array = $.parseJSON( '{"total":1,"movies":[{"id":"770672122","title":"Toy Story 3","year":2010,"mpaa_rating":"G","runtime":103,"critics_consensus":"Deftly blending comedy, adventure, and honest emotion, Toy   Story 3 is a rare second sequel that really works.","release_dates":{"theater":"2010-06-18","dvd":"2010-11-02"},"ratings":{"critics_rating":"Certified Fresh","critics_score":99,"audience_rating":"Upright"}}]}');

Answer (score 0):

The Gson library is really helpful for parsing JSON:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Emil's tutorial above can help you get started

Others have suggested Jackson so [here is a stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson) that compares them: