# Jackson Vs. Gson (Revisited)

Tags: java, json, comparison, jackson, gson

I have been looking around the internet to try and find the best Java to Json library. I've come across quite a few old threads ([Jackson Vs. Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson)), but nothing very recent.  The two libraries I am interested in are:

- Jackson
- Gson

I am leaning towards using Gson, but would love some *up-to-date* help in comparing the two since both libraries are constantly being updated. Most of the benchmark comparisons I was able to find were between 1 and 2 years old ([Android Json Parsers](http://www.martinadamek.com/2011/02/04/json-parsers-performance-on-android-with-warmup-and-multiple-iterations/)).

Comment: What do you want to do with them? I used Gson in a standalone fashion and moved on to Jackson b/c it's the default provider for my JAX-RS implementation. Has been *way* more important than any performance comparison. So without a clear goal you're not likely to get meaningful answers.

Comment: Here is a recent compare of the two: http://blaazinsoftwaretech.blogspot.dk/2013/08/jackson-2-vs-gson-performance-comparison.html