# What is performance overhead of JSON to JAVA object and vice versa

Tags: json

In my project I need to convert json to java object and vice versa multiple times.Using standard object mapper we can do this but does it have considerable performance overhead? Is there any number published ? I could not find much info it .I ran a test but in high throughput low latency framework not sure if it is good idea and should try some alternate. 
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378402/jackson-vs-gson).
All in all, Jackson is considered to be faster, but I've also read that gson gives better performance when working with large objects.